# What type of text is ths and which CSS rule i use to do text like this

Tags: html, css

i want to make same design in html css. kindly tell me how to align header text like this. i no where find this on internet.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [aztemplates.org](http://www.aztemplates.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Payment-Receipt-Template.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You mean the green part? What exactly do you searched on google? Just search for "css rotation" or "css text rotation"...?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.rotate{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#header { 
         -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
           position: fixed;
             right: 0;
             top: 0;
                }
```

Comment: why i got -4 for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Right, I have made a little example for you. Have a look around and mess around with it as much as you want. The other people are correct using `transform` but as no one has made an example I may as well.

### HTML:

```
<div id="con">
    <div id="header"><h2>Side Header</h2>
        <p>Test line, more random text</p></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#con {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
#header {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    background: #eee;
    height:100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);/* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);/* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7Bq95/1/)

So we create the `div` that will hold the header and after you have created it as you want it use `transform` to rotate it. I have added the other browsers in as well.